# Pass objects to Dynamic Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, codedom

I have some types whose objects i need to pass to a dynamic assembly. But my types are not recognised and i am getting compile errors

Here is my code to compile

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SkillBuilder.AutoGens.Libs;

namespace TempNs
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {}

        public Autozen ag; 
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

The above code throws error saying that `type Autozen could not be found. Are you missing an Assembly reference?`. The type is in `SkillBuilder.AutoGens.Libs`.

This is how i compile it.

```
public static Assembly Compile(string sourceCode)
    {
        var provider_options = new Dictionary<string, string>
                     {
                         {"CompilerVersion","v4.0"}
                     };
        CodeDomProvider cpd = new CSharpCodeProvider(provider_options);
        var cp = new CompilerParameters();
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Core.Dll");

        // True - memory generation, false - external file generation
        cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
        cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
        CompilerResults cr = cpd.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, sourceCode);

        if (cr.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (CompilerError error in cr.Errors)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(String.Format("Error ({0}): {1}", error.ErrorNumber, error.ErrorText));
            }

            throw new InvalidOperationException(sb.ToString());
        }

        return cr.CompiledAssembly;
    }
```

I want to be able to assign the value of "ag" by the calling application.
How do i make Autozen available during compile time ? Is there any other way?

**EDIT** :
The code is generated and compiled by an EXE. The compiled output is again going to be used by the same EXE.
thanks for your help.

**EDIT** :
After adding Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location to the referenced assembly collection now i get System.Core.dll missing referece error. Since i have included CompilerVersion, it should pickup the assembly from the GAC. Then why am i still getting this error ?

Comment: Append the reference: `cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("SkillBuilder.AutoGens.Libs.dll");`

Comment: @MarkShevchenko thanks. That namespace is not a dll. it is an exe which is creating the dynamic code and compiling too.

Comment: In that case, add the exe as reference. Whatever contains the namespace ;)

Comment: @olydis Added cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("SkillBuilder.exe"); still no luck :(

Comment: the error is still the same? Try using the fully path of your exe: `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`

Comment: @olydis Thanks olydis. That error is gone now. but now i am getting  System.core.dll is missing reference.